# Selenium - webdriver - Python - Duplicate webdriver Script and run to another tab by change some value from excel like

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have single script Selenium webdriver By Python Language.
script open one tab and I send key to webdriver from Excel

Comment: I'm not sure if two processes can use the same browser. I think every process will have to use own browser. And I'm not sure if Selenium can run code in two tabs in the same time - second tab will have to wait until Selenium ends working in first tab.

Comment: selenium can works only with actve tab. To send keys to different tab it has to switch to this tab so it can't send keys to two tabs at the same time. It is Do you have to use Selenium? Using `requests+BeautifulSoup` you could run the same code in many threads or multiprocesses. And it doesn't have to wait to load full page. But it needs more code and it may not work if page uses JavaScript.